# Cannot iterate the HashMap converted as JSON String in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, hashmap

How to make the video button always appear when playing videos?
Now the button only appears when we click the video, please help me.
This is my code

**In Spring Controller: Returning the Map values as JSON String**

```
Map<String, Long> keyTTLMap = getRedisCacheTTLvalues(filterPattern);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

jsonObject.put("cacheTTLmap", keyTTLMap);

return jsonObject.toString();
```

**In JSP AJAX call:**

```
var json = xmlhttp.responseText;

for ( var i = 0; i < json.cacheTTLmap.length; i++) {
    var obj = json.cacheTTLmap[i];  
    for ( var key in obj) {
        name = key;
        value = obj[key].toString();
        alert("Name "+name +" value "+value);
    }
}
```

**JSON String value:**

```
{
    "cacheTTLmap":
    {
        "product1":81213,    
        "product2":79936
    }   
}
```

When I try to run my `JSP`, my `JSON` string cannot be iterated. Is there any simple way to display `HashMap` in `AJAX`, Kindly help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = '[{"userId" : "123123", "password": "fafafa", "age": "21"}, {"userId" :  
"321321", "password" : "nana123", "age" : "34"}]';

var list = JSON.parse(json);
var output = {};

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
    for(var key in list[i])
    {
        if(list[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            if(typeof output[key] == 'undefined')
            {
                output[key] = [];
            }
            output[key].push(list[i][key]);
        }
    }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
```